# VS Code how to configure a project with isolated type system per individual Js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

The problem.
I want to have a folder with multiple ES5 JavaScript files.

By default the JavaScript/Typescript workspace treats all files as a single project, so variables defined in one js file are visible in any other file in the project.

Unfortunately these files are used for scripting a desktop application and they are executed in different typing contexts, so sharing the variables is not be permitted.

How to configure my workspace in VSCode, (eventually via an extension ) to achieve type system isolation between these files.
I cannot use any type of module imports.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
Put files in separate folders.
Create a jsconfig.json file in each folder with content {}.